# How to run programs and scripts NOT in the background on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to remotely execute some scripts and run some programs on a remote virtual machine on a server. The command I have been using is Invoke-command After going through all the troubles to make it work properly with the right authentications and credentials and internal password, I now can finally invoke some executables from my local computer. However, as I was trying to run notepad.exe, it only showed up in the background processes, meaning that I couldnt see any notepad UI whatsoever. Does anyone know what the solution to this is ? Thank you!

Comment: Already asked on SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902760/how-to-run-programs-and-scripts-not-in-the-background-on-a-remote-machine. Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question to multiple sites of the SE network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using powershell, sadly I don't. I'd be glad to offer a bounty for someone else to find though!

For this, I use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx). It's fairly simple to use and has a switch to run interactive processes.

While typing this answer, I saw [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context), and the #1 answer is that it's a security limitation of powershell, so it may not be possible at all, even in the future.

Comment: Oh if that's really the case then it's too bad.
However thanks for the info though. I can use psexec but that requires the special tool sadly.

Comment: Hello Mike,

    Thank you for your post on Super user. I am still having some issues with Psexec.
    As it turned out, it also launches programs in the background. I have tried with several Windows built-in apps like mspaint.exe, notepad.exe and calc.exe but none of them seem to have any GUI visible to me. Is there an option for PsExec to make it run visibly? I have tried -i, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @FrozenLand you might want to try `psexec.exe -accepteula -s -i -h yourApp.exe`, don't forget -accepteula or it will 'invisibly' hang there.

Comment: I have tried that also. For some reason it just refuses to show up... It is frustrating